# How can I stage additional files with my Google Cloud Dataflow pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

My code:

```
Foo bar = new Foo("somefile.gz");
```

When I run it on Google Dataflow stream, it can not find my **somefile.gz**.
How to staging resource file to Google Dataflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, all the files on the classpath are uploaded. If you include the desired file as a resource in your jar, then it will be uploaded by this process. You can then access the file via the [Java resources APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html).

If this does not work for your situation, you can use [setFilesToStage](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.java#L200), which is `--filesToStage` on the command line. Note that this overrides the automatic classpath uploading, so you will then also need to explicitly upload your library dependencies.

Comment: Hi Kenn, How would be specify our library dependencies and classpath files which are currently being picked up automatically? Want to stage some dat files, but then not sure how to include the current implicit list in the param. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `setFilesToStage`, which on the command line is `--fileToStage`.